# Keep an NSWindow on the bottom in OS X

Tags: swift, nswindow

I really love [Conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky) whenever I am working in linux, but I can't find anything like it for OS X, so I figured I would make it myself.

I am having a hard time setting up the NSWindow to be always in the back. I know that you can get the window to sick in the front with

```swift
self.window!.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey.MaximumWindowLevelKey))
```

however, I want my Conky window to stay behind everything else, basically at the same level as my desktop back ground (although it would be fine if it were above icons on the desktop). I can't get it to do that though. I've tried using MinimumWindowLevelKey instead of MaximumWindowLevelKey, but then my window just disappeared and I couldn't find it anywhere (yes, I did move xCode out of the way.

Comment: Hi! Do you have, by any chance, ever figured this out?